# Retrieve "Member of" groups and permissions from a specific user on Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to figure out how can I run a poweshell command to retrieve a specific user "Member of" groups and permissions to folders to an Excel file or text file.
I've searched a bit and I've only come up to the command:

```
(Get-ACL "AD:$((Get-ADUser -Identity '(user)').distinguishedname)").access | Select IdentityReference,AccessControlType
```

Any thoughts on this? Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That gets permissions to the user object in Active Directory. I don't think that's what you want. Just search Google for "powershell get active directory user groups" and "powershell get folder permissions"

Comment: If you're trying to figure out what folders a user has access to, that's not stored in AD. You will have to look at the permissions of every folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File permissions are not stored in AD Objects but on the directory themselves. To achieve this you would need to review the individual folders or use the cmdlet you provided. To automate (reviewing ACL's) I would use a loop.

To review group membership of an AD Object you can use the `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet or use `Get-ADGroupMember` for a particular group. Hope this helps.